# Translating Screen Coordinates [ x, y ] to Camera Pan and Tilt angles

Tags: math, camera, trigonometry

I have a IP Camera which can PTZ. I am currently streaming live feed into the browser and want to allow user to click a point on the screen and the camera will pan and tilt so that the user clicked position will now become the center point of view.

my Camera Pan 360 degrees and Tilt from -55 to 90.

any algorithm that will guide to me achieve my goal ??

Comment: obtain/measure FOV of your camera then convert pixel position to angle by linear interpolation and that is it your actual position is center pixel so the distance from center in x and y will get you the movement angles directly

Comment: I have the FOV of the camera which is 65 degree.. its a not a linear interpolation.. when the camera is looking straight without tilt its ok to linearly interpolate but when there is tilt the value is not linear.. More like the camera is a spherical dome

Comment: unless you got some weird anti fish eye lenses or filters then it is linear. The problem you are describing looks more like wrong order of transformations. The camera FOV has 2 angles btw horizxontal and vertical. Also what is the kinematics of the camera if the rotations centers are not the same and in focal point then you need to apply geometry corrections but for that you need to share the geometry ...

Answer (score 3):

Let's start by declaring a 3D coordinate system around the camera (the origin). I will use the following: The z-axis points upwards. The x-axis is the camera direction with `pan=tilt=0` and positive pan angles will move the camera towards the positive y-axis.

Then, the transform for a given pan/tilt configuration is:

```
T = Ry(-tilt) * Rz(pan)
```

This is the transform that positions our virtual image plane in 3D space. Let's keep that in mind and go to the image plane.

If we know the vertical and horizontal field of view and assume that lens distortions are already corrected, we can set up our image plane as follows: The image plane is 1 unit away from the camera (just by declaration) in the view direction. Let the center be the plane's local origin. Then, its horizontal extents are `+- tan(fovx / 2)` and its vertical extents are `+- tan(fovy / 2)`.

Now, given a pixel position `(x, y)` in this image (origin in the top left corner), we first need to convert this location into a 3D direction. We start by calculating the local coordinates in the image plane. This is for the image's pixel width `w` and pixel height `h`:

```
lx = (2 * x / w - 1) * tan(fovx / 2)
ly = (-2 * y / h + 1) * tan(fovy / 2)   (local y-axis points upwards)
lz = 1                                  (image plane is 1 unit away)
```

This is the ray that contains the according pixel under the assumption that there is no pan or tilt yet. But now it is time to get rid of this assumption. That's where our initial transform comes into play. We just need to transform this ray:

```
tx = cos(pan) * cos(tilt) * lx - cos(tilt) * sin(pan) * ly - sin(tilt) * lz
ty = sin(pan)             * lx + cos(pan)             * ly
tz = cos(pan) * sin(tilt) * lx - sin(pan) * sin(tilt) * ly + cos(tilt) * lz
```

The resulting direction now describes the ray that contains the specified pixel in the global coordinate system that we set up in the beginning. All that's left is calculate the new pan/tilt parameters:

```
tilt = atan2(tz, tx)
pan  = asin(ty / sqrt(tx^2 + ty^2 + tz^2))
```

Comment: tx = ...
ty = ...
tz = ...
as I understand in this formula, pan and tilt values are in degrees, and I assume that they are current PTZ status.
However, ONVIF pan and tilt values range from -1 to 1, how can I convert the ONVIF pan/tilt to the desired degrees to calculate tx, ty, tz.
tilt = atan2(tz, tx)
pan  = asin(ty / sqrt(tx^2 + ty^2 + tz^2))
how can I convert final pan/tilt values from degrees to the ONVIF range?
ONVIF: https://github.com/FalkTannhaeuser/python-onvif-zeep